How can I make an adapter wiring for a TRRS microphone to TRS?
I'm making a sound level meter using a Raspberry Pi as part of my thesis.  My professor has given me a TRRS microphone to work with.
I tried to make the TRRS microphone work with the Raspberry Pi using an external sound card and a TRRS to TRS adaptor, but the resulting input is much too weak for adequate results.
My professor suggested I try to make a cable on my own and see if this will improve the input, which brings me to my question.
What wiring should I make for a TRRS s to TRS adapter microphone?
The microphone I'm using is the Dayton imm-6, which it is a CTIA type TRRS.
I want to connect it to the ORICO SC2 soundcard.

For TRRS CTIA:

Sleeve = mic
Ring = GND (for mic and speakers)
Ring = (right speaker, not used for mic)
Tip = (left speaker, not used for mic)

For TRS mic only:

Sleeve = GND
Ring = (not connected or connected to mic)
Tip = mic

You can verify if your current adapter already provides this pinout before making your own adapter, as then the results will be identical.
Also the adapter may be unnecessary, as the sound card has a headset port already.
If the mic is equally poor in the headset port, and on the mic port with adapter, then your custom adapter will likely not help at all.
